# How can I check if a computer on my network is online?

Tags: c#, .net

I want to know how to check if a machine on my network is online, using only C#.

All machines on my network use the same OS (Windows 7) and I'm logged in as the same user on all machines.

My goal is to check if they are active, or open.

Comment: how about ping ? How do you define 'active', 'open' ?

Comment: i absolutely need to use c# code

Comment: @pharaon450: you can start `ping` from C# code as well :-P

Comment: if the machine is on, like if the machine is open

Comment: @pharaon450 Someone turns on the computer, then unplugs the network cable.

Comment: @vlad i dont worry about the cable it will always be plugged

Comment: Until some tech or cleaning person comes by. A tech may yank the line to use to put another machine online (seen this happen), and cleaning crew may yank the line cause its in their way (seen this happen). Just pointing out that the stupidest things happen with cables and machines that aren't always under your watchful guard.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Simple:

```
Ping ping = new Ping();
PingReply pingReply = ping.Send("ip address here");

if(pingReply.Status == IPStatus.Success)
{
   //Machine is alive
}
```

Comment: Any alternate way to check if the computer is active? Ping service can be disabled in machines you know.

Comment: @NinethSense any solution about it if ping Service can be disabled ?

Comment: Well, you can check if any port is open. But looping will be time consuming.

Answer (score 6):

The best you can probably hope for without installing some custom software on the target machine is to [use the Ping class.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.networkinformation.ping.aspx)

A quick and dirty implementation might look like this:

```
var p = new Ping();
if(p.Send("HostNameOrIP").Status != Success) return;
```

If you have very specific requirements about what an "active and open" machine is, and the state can only be detected locally, you will need to write a windows service that will expose a WCF service. This service will run on the target computer and report back the local status when requested by the source computer.