# Cancel a .C# Net BackgroundWorker blocked on I/O operation

Tags: .net, backgroundworker

I'm required to use Framework 3.5. I want to test whether a file on another computer named BOB exists. I'm using a BackgroundWorker and File.Exists(fileName). If BOB is offline the call will block for tens of seconds. Abort() and Interrupt() have no effect while the worker is waiting for the call to File.Exists() to return. I'd like to interrupt File.Exists() immediately. Can anyone suggest a way to do this that doesn't involve p/invoke?

Thanks.

To clarify, I need to periodically check to see whether the file is available. I can't know whether the remote computer is configured to respond to pings. I'm running as a standard user, not admin. I have no access to the remote system administrators.

It looks like Framework 4.0 or 4.5 has some async capability that would help with this but I'm restricted to 3.5.

Editing to add test program:

```
// First call to File.Exists waits at least 20 seconds the first time the
// remote computer is taken off line. To demonstrate, set TestFile to the name
// of a file on a remote computer and start the program. Then disable the 
// remote computer's network connection. Each time you disable it the test
// program pauses. In my test the local computer runs Win8 and remote WinXp
// in a VirtualBox VM.
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Threading;
using System.ComponentModel;
namespace Block2
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            AutoResetEvent autoResetEvent = new AutoResetEvent(false);
            BackgroundWorker worker = new BackgroundWorker();
            worker.DoWork += DoWork;
            worker.RunWorkerAsync(autoResetEvent);
            log("main - waiting");
            autoResetEvent.WaitOne();
            log("main - finished");
        }

        static void DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
        {
            const string TestFile = @"p:\TestFile.txt";
            for (int x = 0; x < 100; x++)
            {
                if (File.Exists(TestFile))
                    log("  -- worker: file exists");
                else
                    log("  -- worker: file doesn't exist");
                Thread.Sleep(1000);
            }
            ((AutoResetEvent)e.Argument).Set();
        }

        static void log(string msg)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(DateTime.Now.ToLocalTime().ToString()+": "+ msg);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Start a BackgroundWorkerThread, call File.Exists() on a file on a remote computer that is not connected to the network. The thread blocks for 30 or more seconds. You can't interrupt it from the main thread. I don't think sample code would add anything. The call blocks. It's different than win32 programming. What's the -1 for?

Comment: The point of `BackgroundWorker` is that it runs in a separate thread. So if you call `File.Exists` in a `BackgroundWorker` it will not block your main thread. Are you sure you're using it correctly? This is why I asked you to post your code (please do so in your main post.) Also, I'm not the one that downvoted you.

Comment: Ok, good. That's right, I'm calling File.Exists on a worker thread and that thread, not the main thread blocks. The call to File.Exists is a blocking call; I presume the worker thread is in some I/O pending queue (as opposed to  a Sleep queue or something, where it can be Interrupted or Aborted). If, on the UI or main thread the user wants to exit the program I'd like to be able to ask the worker to exit gracefully. Abort and Interrupt have no effect until the call to File.Exists returns.  *** Separately It seems spooky that someone can down-vote you without stating a reason. Not very nice.***

Comment: *Please edit your post and paste the code you've tried.* This is a programming forum, after all.

Answer (score 0):

Follow these steps:

1. First check if remote Computer is online: [How can I check if a computer on my network is online?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10818229/how-can-i-check-if-a-computer-on-my-network-is-online)
2. If its online go ahead with checking File.Exists(), else abort the operation.

Comment: I need to periodically check to see if the file exists so it may the first time but not afterwards. That is, if the network goes down then the call to File.Exists will take 30 to 60 seconds (depending on some socket timeout, I assume) before it returns. Thanks.

Comment: Periodically means? How often? How about every time you check File.Exists, check if server is online. Do a POC and see how much time it takes.

Answer (score 0):

Although `BackgroundWorker` has a `CancelAsync` method, this is merely a *request* to cancel. From [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dxbk2sy2%28v=vs.90%29.aspx):

> The worker code should periodically check the CancellationPending
>   property to see if it has been set to **true**.

Obviously this is not an option for you, so you will have to use the lower-level `Thread` construct. There is an `Abort` method which will terminate the thread.

You can then update your main as follows:

```
Thread worker = new Thread(DoWork);
worker.Start();
log("main - waiting");
log("Press any key to terminate the thread...");
Console.ReadKey();
worker.Abort();
log("main - finished");
```

Your `DoWork` function remains the same, except it doesn't take any arguments. Now your program will sit there checking for the file, but if you press a key, the thread will terminate.

You can't use an `AutoResetEvent` object because if you do, then your main thread blocks as before until `DoWork` completes.

Answer (score 0):

I posted this question because I saw that File.Exists would block for an extended period of time if the remote computer was offline. The delay occurs the first time it is called when the computer is offline. Subsequent calls return immediately; it appears Widows caches something that it uses during those subsequent calls.

If you run the program and toggle the remote computer's connection between enabled and disabled you'll see the delay in the program's output. The purpose of the program is to illustrate that delay. That's all.

Thank you to everyone for your time. I'll rethink my approach based on your inputs.